# If $n \geq N_0$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n}.$ Does this have a name?

Tags: convergence-divergence, reference-request

Suppose we have a sequence $f_n$ of real-valued functions and a function $f$ such that: there exists an $N_0$ such that if $n \geq N_0$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n}.$ Either for all $x$ uniformly or not. does this type of convergence have a name?

Comment: This is equivalent to the usual definitions of uniform/pointwise convergence

Comment: @Lukas the usual one says: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_0=N_0(\epsilon)$ such that if $n \geq N_0$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$. How can I select $\epsilon=\frac 1n$?

Comment: If we have the usual definition we can choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ as a special case. If we know that the "modified" version holds we can use that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to zero. So: $\forall \epsilon >0$ exists an $N_0$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Combine this with the given property and we find a $N_1$ s.t. $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N_1$.

Comment: @Lukas The modified one implies the usual but I don't see why the usual implies the modified. You are saying "there exists $N_0$ depending on $n$ such that $n \geq N_0(n)$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac 1n$." That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You are right. The problem is that the $n$ in $f_n$ and in $\frac{1}{n}$ are the same number.

Comment: This probably doesn't have a name, but studying the speed of convergence (e.g. $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<1/n, 1/n^2, e^{-n}$ etc.) is important in (numerical) analysis.